# Vite: Add CSS file to end of <head> section

Tags: css, vite

We are using Vite and would like to manually load an external CSS file. Internally to the project we are using CSS modules. We need the external CSS file to load after the CSS generated by CSS modules.

In `vite.config.js` I have tried to add a plugin that adds the stylesheet link to the head section as follows.

```js
function externalCSSPlugin() {
  return {
    name: 'external-css',
    transformIndexHtml: {
      enforce: 'post',
      transform(html, ctx) {
        return [{
          tag: "link",
          attrs: {"rel": "stylesheet", "type":"text/css", "href": "/*<link to css>*/"},
          injectTo: "head"
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, this always results in the stylesheets generated by CSS modules to be appended to the head after the external CSS:

```
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/external-css.css">
  /* styles generated by CSS modules */
</head>
```

We don't want this, as the external CSS sets some CSS variables.

How can we force the external stylesheet to be added to the end of the head section?

Answer (score 3):

The problem only occurs while using the dev server (and not in a build). Since the CSS module styles are always appended to `<head>` in the dev server, you can ensure your `<link>` is after those styles by injecting into the beginning of `<body>`. This should be done for the dev server only (in which case the plugin's `ctx.server` exists), as Vite already appends the `<link>` correctly to `<head>` in production builds:

```js
function externalCSSPlugin() {
  return {
    name: 'external-css',
    transformIndexHtml: {
      enforce: 'post',
      transform(html, ctx) {
        return [{
          tag: "link",
          attrs: {"rel": "stylesheet", "type":"text/css", "href": "/*<link to css>*/"},
          injectTo: ctx.server ? "body-prepend" : "head", 
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-plugin-to-append-link-to-head-zbvbxd?file=vite.config.js)